# Run main exe with the possibility to have a crash dump writer enabled

Tags: c#, wpf

I was wondering if it's possible to have for a WPF application the possibility to run the main exe with a parameter that loads in memory a process monitor that at main exe's death (I've on a certain customer, on a single machine, where the client crashes without writing anything). Since creating the dump from inside would lead to having the client stack shifted to the exception handler), I wish to have a process monitor that intercepts application death and make the dump for it

Comment: Did you try the FinalExceptionHandler to catch your app's death. There you have access to the stack trace and write what ever you want to a file.

Comment: Did you take a look into the Eventviewer's application log? A couple of years ago something like your problem happen to me and after looking at the eventviewer it happened to be a framework issue, my app did not even started, it crashed at the very beginning.

Comment: FinalExceptionHandler is a part of .NET enviorment? or do you mean      `DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException` or `            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;`